# What are the penalties associated with various crimes?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

UESP has this list of illegal actions one can perform:

> - Stealing items or horses
> - Pickpocketing (although just looking at someone's inventory is not a
>     crime)
> - Lockpicking
> - Killing farm animals
> - Trespassing
> - Starting a fight (but not a brawl)
> - Killing a non-aggressive character
> - Dropping a weapon outdoors in a major city can result in a warning
>     from a guard, refusing to pick it up will result in a bounty
> - Transforming into werewolf form in public will give a 1000 gold
>     bounty
> - Eating a corpse by using the Ring of Namira
> - Shouting in a town may result in a warning from a guard.

However, they don't specify what bounty is associated with every action.  Does anyone have this information, or could they build and provide it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- For stealing items it is half of the item's worth
- For stealing a horse it is 250
- For lockpicking it is 25 or 5 (I don't remember)
- Killing animals counts as combat (40)
- I haven't noticed any bounty for Trespassing
- Starting a fight is combat (40)
- Killing is murder (1000)
- Harmless Shouting won't ever result in bounty, only a warning.
- Shouting that results in injury or death of a non-hostile entity will be penalized appropriately as a violent crime.

Comment: "Killing is murder" :D

Comment: Will shouting not count as combat or murder in some cases?

Comment: @Iszi only if you kill someone with it. If you maim someone, it's an assault.  If it's a non-violent shout, you just get a warning.

Comment: @Iszi most likely that Shouting someone off a cliff will also be considered murder.. the answer is correct for just Shouting for your pleasure without any casualties. :-)

Comment: What about time served in jail for the amount of gold on your bounty (should you choose to go to jail)?  Can you put that into your answer as well?

Comment: @Iszi if you shout an aggressive shout (like force thing,fire breath, frost berath, marked for death, storm call and another something I don't remember) and kill someone then it's 1040 (murder + combat) and if you just hurt someone it's 40

Comment: I think trespassing is 5 gold (in a civilian house at least).